# Only publish messages to RabbitMQ if database transaction is successful using Spring AMQP

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-transactions, spring-amqp

Let's say I have a method that looks something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void x(Entity entity) {
    // do something
    myRepository.save(entity);
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(new Event1());
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(new Event2());
}
```

`myRepository` is using a transaction manager of type `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager`. What I want to do is to make sure that the sending of `Event1` and `Event2` only happens if `myRepository.save(entity)` is successful. Does [RabbitTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring-amqp/docs/latest_ga/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/transaction/RabbitTransactionManager.html) help here or do I have to implement this myself (for example using a [TransactionSynchronizationManager](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What calls `x()` ?

If it's a RabbitMQ listener container thread after receiving some message from rabbit, add the JpaTransactionManager to the container and the rabbit transaction will be synchronized for you.

If it's some arbitrary thread then you'll need to start a rabbit transaction before calling x and commit it afterwards.

In either case, your rabbit channel needs to be transactional.

Comment: x is called by an arbitrary thread. Can the use of a "spring rabbit transaction" (using RabbitTransactionManager) make sure that Event1 and Event2 are sent atomically?

Comment: Yes; and (as long as you start the tx before calling x) if the DB tx rolls back so will the rabbit tx. You can either wrap `x` in another transactional method  using the Rabbit TM, or create a chained TM as described in [Dave Syer's Javaworld article: Distributed transactions in Spring, with and without XA](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html).

Comment: What if TM1 (messaging) and TM2 (db) are chained (and thus used by Transactional annotated methods) but in method y we only do writes to the db (without publishing events). Would the automatic use of a chained TM for all Transactional annoyed methods cause any "significant" performance penalties compared to if we would explicitly start the chained TM only on methods that require such chaining?

Comment: As long as you increase the `channelCacheSize` in the `CachingConnectionFactory` it would be insignificant - we'd just get a channel from the cache and return it without doing any work with it. If the cache is exhausted (default 1), it would cause 2 round trips to the broker - create and close channel for no reason.